# Game collision detection between many objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, collision-detection

I'm trying to understand how to implement collision detection between multiple object.
My project detects the collision between the objects but it crashes immediately after.

This is my main class with the `JFrame` and `Main Loop`:

```
public class Window {

public static void main(String[] args){
    GamePanel gamepanel = new GamePanel();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Multiple Collision Detection");
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.add(gamepanel);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    while(true){
        gamepanel.repaint();
        gamepanel.update();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Main Loop Error");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Then i have two classes, one for the player and one for the enemy:

PLAYER:

```
public class Player {

int x = 175, y = 175, w = 50, h = 50, dx = 0, dy = 0;
Rectangle rect;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
}

public void setDx(int dx) {
    this.dx = dx;
}

public void setDy(int dy) {
    this.dy = dy;
}

public void move() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public void update() {
    move();
}

}
```

ENEMY:

```
public class Enemy {

int x, y, w = 35, h = 35;

Rectangle rect;

public Enemy(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

public void update() {

}

}
```

I've the EnemyManager class that draws more than one enemy (in this case 3) through a `List`:

```
public class EnemyManager {

Player player = new Player();
Rectangle playerrect;
Rectangle enemyrect;
List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    enemies.add(new Enemy(20, 20));
    enemies.add(new Enemy(320, 20));
    enemies.add(new Enemy(20, 320));

    for (Enemy e : enemies) {
        e.paint(g);
    }
}

public void update() {

}

}
```

Finally i've the GamePanel class that draws the `Graphics` from the other classes (`Player` and `EnemyManager`):

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

Player player = new Player();
EnemyManager enemymanager = new EnemyManager();

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    player.paint(g);
    enemymanager.paint(g);
}

public void checkPlayerEnemyCollision(){
    for(Enemy e : enemymanager.enemies){
        if(e.rect.intersects(player.rect)){
            System.out.println("Collision");
        }
    }
}

public void update(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    player.update();
    enemymanager.update();
    checkPlayerEnemyCollision();
}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        player.setDy(-2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        player.setDy(2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
        player.setDx(-2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        player.setDx(2);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        player.setDy(0);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        player.setDy(0);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
        player.setDx(0);
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        player.setDx(0);
    }
}
}
```

When the game detects a collision between the player and an enemy, it prints "Collision" to the console but after that it crashes with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at GamePanel.checkPlayerEnemyCollision(GamePanel.java:22)
at GamePanel.update(GamePanel.java:34)
at Window.main(Window.java:20)
```

Anyone knows what is the problem and maybe how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paint` is called from the event dispatcher thread. You modify the list in this method

```
event dispatcher thread
-> GamePanel.paint
-> EnemyManager.paint
-> enemies.add
```

However you use a iterator of the list through the "foreach" loop in `GamePanel.checkPlayerEnemyCollision`:

```
for(Enemy e : enemymanager.enemies)
```

But the iterator of `ArrayList` fails, if you modify the list after the iterator is created with the exception you got.

Since the list modification and the iterator can are used from different threads they can easyly interfere, e.g.:

1. *main thread* creates iterator
2. *main thread* reads a few elements
3. *event dispatcher thread* calls `paint`
4. *event dispatcher thread* adds `Enemy` to list
5. *main thread calls* tries to get a element from the iterator -> exception

---

Your design is a bit flawed:

You have little control, when `paint` is called and as the method name suggests it's used for painting. Don't change the data in this method, just draw it.

Redesign your program keeping that in mind (maybe read a tutorial first, e.g. [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)).

You will still need to read the `Enemy` list from a different thread than the one that modifies the list. Use the `get` method of the list instead of the iterator and keep in mind, that the list **size can change** so you will need to synchronize things a bit. This could be done effectively, if the threads "reserve" a specific index range that they are allowed to access.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your program but couldn't get anything to move, using the keys A, W, S, D. However, I do get a concurrent mod exception like you said, right at the point of a for loop.

Try changing all enhanced loops to normal for loops. For example, in the part

```
for (Enemy e : enemies) {
        e.paint(g);
    }
```

change to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
    enemies.get(i).paint(g);
```

After doing this, I didn't get the error any longer.

Enhanced for loops give you error if you do certain things to an array at certain times. But I'm not sure why in this case, because I'm not too familiar with how graphics work behind the scenes in Java.

Comment: That's not an appropriate (or correct fix).  The only reason it doesn't throw a ConcurrentModificationException is because you don't have an active Iterator.  Instead he's going to end up in one of several bad scenarios, such as 1) Painting the same enemy twice 2) IndexOutOfBounds exceptions when he goes over the limit 3) Not painting enemies because they get added after he's gotten to the last index

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the ConcurrentModificationException, which means you're attempting to modify a collection in one thread while iterating over it in another (this can also happen within a single thread if you attempt to modify the collection while iterating, but that's not what's happening here).

This all stems from the fact you're not paying attention to which thread your events are happening in. You've got two active threads, whether you realize it or not.

*Thread #1 is the programs Main thread, which is where the app starts from*

*Thread #2 is the Swing EDT, where all of your user actions initiate from.*

It looks like you're trying to update your domain model from the Main thread while iterating over collections from the Swing EDT.  You either need to synchronize access or make all your updates perform on the EDT by wrapping it in an invoke later:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    gamepanel.repaint();
    gamepanel.update();
  }
});
```

Note that I don't know that simply using the above snippet in a loop+Thread.sleep is the correct action in this case, as I haven't gone through all your logic.  At the very least you should read a [tutorial on Swing threading.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)